# How to bind CSS/JS when displaying an IndexedDB blob in iframe using "src" attribute and url?

Tags: iframe, blob, indexeddb

I'm currently setting up a web page that use IndexedDB to display html documents in an iframe in this page. This documents are already in the database as blobs. Also, I want to have this web page working online as well as offline. I used [a code from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) to help me start with all this.

Now, I am displaying one document at a time by creating a url pointing to the blob and putting it in the **src** attribute of the iframe. The html documents are displaying well, but because css and javascript files are linked in the html source with urls like "localhost:8080/my_css.css", I'm currently using CSS/JS and images stored on my server, and it will not be helpful once I'll be offline.

My question is : is there a way (quite simple if it is possible) to bind CSS/JS/images stored in the database to the html documents without modifying the html code of this documents to display them perfectly in the iframe ? I think I could use Application Cache API to store locally the files I need, but because there could be lots of CSS and JS files, I'd rather use a way with the IndexedDB API.

Thanks a lot for your answers !

**What my HTML looks like, if it can help :**

```
<ul id="blob-list"> /*List of blobs is generated here */ </ul>
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe"> /*My html documents are displayed here*/ </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
const DB_NAME = 'testdatabase';
  const DB_VERSION = 1; // Use a long long for this value (don't use a float)
  const DB_STORE_NAME = 'publications';

  var db;

 /**
  * @returns Permet d'ouvrir la DB afin de pouvoir l'utiliser
  */
  function openDb() {
    /* Open Database, create a store if not any and display its content. Code based on MDN example */
  }

       /* setInViewer is called every time a blob is clicked in #blob-list */
   function setInViewer(key) {
        var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');
        getBlob(key, store, function(blob) {
          var iframe = newViewerFrame();

          // Set a direct link to the blob to provide a mean to directly load it.
          var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var myframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
          myframe.setAttribute("src", blobURL);
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
        });
      }
   openDB();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose the application cache to achive it. It will be easier to manage and version